# Why does the Software Centre ask me to install untrusted packages?

Tags: software-center, security, software-sources, photo-management

I am trying to install Darktable on my Ubuntu 12.04 64bit desktop computer. When I attempt to install it through the Ubuntu Software Centre I get a warning:

"Requires installation of untrusted packages"

The "Details" are:
darktable libflickcurl0 liblensfun-data liblensfun0

There are two options, OK and Repair. If I choose Repair, it fails to "download repository information".

If I try to add the PPA via terminal and install it, I get cryptic messages about not being able to verify the gpgkey.

Does this mean it is unsafe to install? I would really like to get this running (safely) as I am a professional photographer and I want to share my workflow with the Linux community.

Thanks

Comment: On a side note, can you post the error message you get when trying to get the GPG key? I can update my answer to be more complete. Hopefully I can give you some commands to actually fix the issue rather than ignoring it.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was a network problem, which explains the *407 Proxy Authentication* errors.

From System Settings I went to Network. I clicked on my proxy connection, selected Configure, and noticed the proxy was set to "Connect Automatically". I disabled the automatic proxy connection and was able to update and install software again without problems.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this "untrusted" error is because of the GPG key download failure. Modern repositories are signed with a private GPG key and they distribute a public GPG key so that the signature can be verified by end-users.

Theoretically this helps to prevent package downloads in the case that somebody replaces a package on the repository site with an unsigned version (may contain malware, spyware, etc.) This assumes that the "attacker" doesn't have the private GPG key to sign the packages.

So, you're getting the error because of the failed GPG key download. Apt can't verify the integrity of the package signature because it doesn't have the public key available to decrypt it.

Generally, it's not a good idea to download/install unverified software. But if you know the software and trust it, you can go ahead and install it without worries.

Comment: Thank you. I've been worried to install it because of this. So do the software maintainers need to update their public GPG key or something. Or is there a problem on my end downloading it?

Comment: I don't know, you didn't post the output ;)

Comment: Oh sorry. Good point ;) It's long, I'll try and fit it in the next comment. And thanks for all your help.

Comment: W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
, W:Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
, W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/precise-getdeb/games/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required

Comment: It keeps going like that for another 9000 characters and ends with:  W:Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
, W:Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
, W:Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Are you... behind a proxy?

Comment: No, I shouldn't be. I connect to Open VPN from time to time to watch American Netflix, but I am on my regular connection now.

Comment: Double check the proxy settings in System Settings > Network. And is Firefox set to use the global proxy or something else?

Comment: In System Settings > Network, Proxy is set to none. In Firefox it is currently set to Use System Proxy Settings.

Comment: Hmm... have you tried switching the repositories to perhaps the US servers or the general servers? (Software Sources)